# How to get datepart of date today within a function in Python code?

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I needed to run a function in Python that checks the day and month today, together with another indicator/flag, to determine whether to run a code for monthly records only or to run codes for both monthly and quarterly records.

I got an error, saying "***global name 'month' is not defined***".

I tried the statement "***month(current_timestamp)***" as part of a PySpark sqlContext code, and it worked fine.

I also tried changing "***current_timestamp***" to "***datetime.now()***", but got the same error.

```
def testing():
    conn = pymssql.connect(server='xx.xx.xx.xxx', user='user', password='password', database='database')
    stmt="select flag from dbo.score_flag"      
    lead_pd = pd.read_sql(stmt,conn)
    lead_flag=lead_pd.at[0,'flag']

    if lead_flag == 'Y' and month(current_timestamp) in (1,4,7,10) and day(current_timestamp) <= 25:
        logMessage("Run Quarterly and Monthly Codes")
        sendEmail('Quarterly and Monthly Records to Score')
        sys.exit(-1)
```

I expect that this code would send an email to me, but got the error message instead.

Comment: Mostly likely you have missed to import "month" in your script..

Answer (score 0):

My colleague just suggested a simple approach - and it worked fine:

```
def testing():
    conn = pymssql.connect(server='xx.xx.xx.xxx', user='user', password='password', database='database')
    stmt="select flag, month(current_timestamp) as month_today, day(current_timestamp) as day_today from dbo.score_flag"      
    lead_pd = pd.read_sql(stmt,conn)

    if lead_pd.at[0,'flag'] == 'Y' and lead_pd.at[0,'month_today'] in (1,4,7,10) and lead_pd.at[0,'day_today'] <= 25:
        logMessage("Run Quarterly and Monthly Codes")
        sendEmail('Quarterly and Monthly Records to Score')
        sys.exit(-1)
```